# Extract number (with different delimiters) from string using REGEXP_SUBSTR in plsql

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I need to extract patterned numbers from I/P string. I have the following patterns:
xxx-xxx-xxxx
xxx xxx-xxxx
xxx  xxx  xxxx

I am using this query to find matching string:

```
select REGEXP_substr('phn: 678 987-0987 Date: 12/2029',
                 '[0-9]{3}(\-|\  |\ )[0-9]{3}(\-|\--|\ )[0-9]{4}')
from dual;
```

I also want to extract the following patterns:
xxxxxx-xxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
etc...

Where do I modify the query?

Comment: You wrote the code, why wouldn't you know better? Please see [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/3622940)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to,

```
[0-9]{3}(\-|\  |\ )?[0-9]{3}(\-|\--|\ )?-?[0-9]{4}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eF8fY4/11)

`(\-|\  |\ )?` turns the whole group as optional. And `-?` turns `-` as optional. The function of `?` after a character literal is, it makes the preceding token as optional.

Comment: Thanks!! By the way, what does `?-?` mean here?

Comment: Thanks! I got confused... I modified the regex to `[0-9]{3}\ ?-?(\  )?[0-9]{3}\ ?-?(\  )?[0-9]{4}`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not always a good approach, since they are high resource consuming feature. I would still use old SUBSTR + INSTR technique :

```
16777216 * to_number(substr(ip, 1, instr(ip, '.', 1, 1) - 1))
     + 65536 * to_number(substr(ip, instr(ip, '.', 1, 1) + 1, instr(ip, '.', 1, 2) - instr(ip, '.', 1, 1) - 1))
     + 256 * to_number(substr(ip, instr(ip, '.', 1, 2) + 1, instr(ip, '.', 1, 3) - instr(ip, '.', 1, 2) - 1))
     + to_number(substr(ip, instr(ip, '.', 1, 3) + 1))
```

**IP# is a simple 32-bit (4 bytes) integer; which is being presented in "dotted quad" format.
Each byte will contain a value between 0 and 255.
so converting to number & using between is as efficient as possible.**